# Combining two lists with different lengths to a single list

Tags: python, list

I was tasked with combining two lists with different lengths to a single list and I'm confused? would it be this simple, or am I missing something. I used these two list as examples. I need to do it with a function.

```
def appArray(x,y):
   List1=[1,2]
   List2=[4,5,6]
   C= List1 + List2
    return C
print (C)
```

Comment: Why you need the variables x,y you dont use them.

Comment: A thousand details are wrong in your code above starting by indentation, or having a function that is not called. But instead of asking for someone to do your homework, why didn't you google first about python lists and see some running examples?